# How to calculate accuracy of a sentiment analysis algorithm (Naive Bayes)

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I'm currently working on a Naive Bayes sentiment analysis program but I'm not quite sure how to determine it's accuracy. My code is:

```
x = df["Text"]
y = df["Mood"]

test_size = 1785
x_train = x[:-test_size]
y_train = y[:-test_size]

x_test = x[-test_size:]
y_test = y[-test_size:]

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(x_train)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)

print(clf.predict(count_vect.transform(["Random text"])))
```

The prediction works just fine for a sentence that I give it, however I want to run it on 20% from my database (x_test and y_test) and calculate the accuracy. I'm not quite sure how to approach this. Any help would be appreciated.

I've also tried the following:

```
predictions = clf.predict(x_test)

print(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "A sentence from the dataset"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before usiing predictions = clf.predict(x_test) please convert the test set also to numeric

```
x_test = count_vect.transform(x_test).toarray()
```

you can find step by step to do this [[here]](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/07/performing-sentiment-analysis-with-naive-bayes-classifier/)

Comment: Thank you, the conversion to numeric worked. Is there any way I can check if I did the prediction correctly? I'm getting around 94% accuracy and I'm not sure that is correct.

Comment: if you are using accuracy_score function to find out the accurancy  and the test  expected labels  y_test  are correct, then the 94% accuracy should be correct. You can cross verify by some sampling and see if you care getting the prediction correctly.  Please accept the answer also if that serve your question.

Comment: Understood, thank you very much for your help.